# Python change a value in a dictionary that is a item in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

Thanks in advance
I want to change a value in a dictionary that is an item in a list

Python 2.6

```
goods1 = {'coal': 1, 'boxes': 2} 
newcastlegoods = goods1
wylamgoods = goods1
goods1 = {}
Newcastle = ['Newcastle' , newcastlegoods]

Wylam = ['Wylam' , wylamgoods]

print Newcastle
print Wylam

Newcastle[1]['coal'] = 4;
print Newcastle
print Wylam
```

My result is

```
['Newcastle', {'coal': 1, 'boxes': 2}]
['Wylam', {'coal': 1, 'boxes': 2}]
['Newcastle', {'coal': 4, 'boxes': 2}]
['Wylam', {'coal': 4, 'boxes': 2}]
```

Note that both coal items have been updated i only want to update newcastle.

Comment: In your code `goods1`, `newcastlegoods`, `wylamgoods` are names of the one `dict` object (until you overwrite `goods1` with an empty `dict`). You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the same dictionary to both lists. When you change one, it's the same as changing the other.

In this case you could get around it by using

```
newcastlegoods = goods1.copy()
wylamgoods = goods1.copy()
```

Which would create a new dictionary for each.

In this case this is fine. If you put mutable objects in your dictionary, you will need to look at a deep copy or the same objects will be referenced within the new dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your list contains a *copy* of the original dictionary, not a reference to it.

```
goods1 = {'coal': 1, 'boxes': 2} 
Newcastle = ['Newcastle' , dict(goods1)]
Wylam = ['Wylam' , dict(goods1)]

print Newcastle
print Wylam

Newcastle[1]['coal'] = 4;
print Newcastle
print Wylam
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to use a package named copy. If you'll have instances in this dictionary the only thing that will help you is copy.deepcopy method.
See here https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for speedy response
All answers worked !!!!!
I had not figured that goods1 was not an independent copy.